# Use Multiprocessing to handle Bulk update in Django

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing, threadpool

I am writing a command that wants to update all rows from my table. Problem is, this table has millions of records. Naively I would want something like this.

```
all_entries = MyTable.objects.all()

for entry in all_entries:
    do_some_magic(entry) # this will do entry.save() after changes
```

My questions is how to successfully use `multiprocessing.Pool` to split this into thread pools? Let's say I want to do batches of 1000 rows and keep running them in thread pools until they are done.

Anyone able to help with code snippet of how this would look?

Comment: There is no need to handle it via Multiprocessing. You can use `Model.objects.bulk_update(model_instance_list, fields_to_update, batch_size)`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update

Comment: But how would I call my method using `bulk_update`? My `do_some_magic` function is doing some tweaks, calculations and then updates in the end

Comment: Can you specify whats your do_some_magic is doing ?

Comment: So for context, my model has a field `object_key` that points to object name inside S3. What I'm doing is, taking the content from S3, encrypting it, creating a new S3 record, and than changing my model `object_key` to point to the new file in S3.

Comment: So for every row I have to talk to S3, update a new document, and re-point my entry to point to the new one. Not sure how `bulk_update` helps there, and I would love to do this in threads in stead to optimize dealing with millions of rows

Comment: Can you show you do some_magic function ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246805/discussion-between-vukojevicf-and-deepak-tripathi).